# Hyperlinks behaves differently in http and https mode

Tags: html, href

I have a jsp page. In that I have multiple links. In http mode, if any link clicked then it opens the target page in the same window.

but in https mode, if any link clicked then it opens the target page in a new window. How to open the target page in the same window when in https mode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe html target attribute has its own options to open link..

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename"> 

<a herf="" target="_parent">LINK</a>
```

should open link in the same parent window instead of popping up new window.

Comment: my page has the same <a herf="" target="_parent">LINK</a>... but not opening the same window, instead it opens the page in new window.. and its a https site